# Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server. xampp error

Tags: php, xampp, http-status-code-404

I want to run a simple html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Untitled.css">

    <title>Connexion</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="" method="post" class="c">
            <p class="l-text" > login</p>
            <div class="i">
                <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" required>
            </div>
            <div class="i">
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="pass" required>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

located in **"C:\xampp\htdocs\chou"** and I get this error

[image]

when I run apache I get the following error [image]

Ps: I've change **Listen 80** to **Listen 8080**

I've also tried so many solutions here but the error still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have another apache instance running. Try to visit http://localhost and see whether the xampp dashboard opens up. If not then we can safely assume that you are still running your other apache instance (c://AppServ/Apache24).

a) Open the task manager and search for a apache24 process. If there's one then end it. And then retry to start the xampp apache server.

Or if you don't need that apache server, you can uninstall it from the system.

If the xampp dashboard comes up by visiting the localhost url, then you are running the xampp server. (please make sure that you have only one xampp server installed)
if so,

a) Are you trying to visit "http://localhost/chou", and then this error comes up?

- Then you may have a redirect script or a .htaccess file with some redirect rule. in the site root.

b) Does this file ("chou/connecter.php" ) exists in the htdocs directory.

c) If the xampp apache is listening on port 8080, Then Did you try to open http://localhost:8080/chou/connecter.php

If nothing above works, Please provide more details.

Comment: You are welcome Wael.  You can accept this as the correct answer if it solved your issue. :D